Clickhouse server - high CPU usage vs memory - anything to balance this better?
I have recently set up a Clickhouse server with 256GB of RAM and 48 cores. The server runs well currently after some tuning of queries. However this is my first Clickhouse server.
Currently the server sits at around 30-40% usage on CPU, and about 5% usage on RAM. I was wondering if there is things that can be done to move some of that CPU workload to RAM.
On a typical database (MySQL/Postgres) I would generate indexes to improve query performance, which would use up memory and reduce CPU workload / speed up queries. However, I believe that Clickhouse Indexes dont work this way - or am I mistaken there? What other features could be used to better balance CPU + memory?

You need to provide the query and schema and the objective of the query. This question is far too broad. You can limit cpu threads used for a query - max_threads (defaults to number of cores) which would cause a better ratio but not RAM usage to change.
